# Casting a struct

Tags: c++

I am currently learning about memory pool implementation.
The thing is i don't quite understand something in the way the type casting is done down below :

```
b3BlockPool::b3BlockPool(u32 blockSize)
{
    m_blockSize = blockSize;
    m_chunkSize = b3_blockCount * m_blockSize;

    m_chunks = NULL;
    m_chunkCount = 0;

    // Pre-allocate some chunks
    b3Chunk* chunk = (b3Chunk*)b3Alloc(sizeof(b3Chunk) + m_chunkSize);
    ++m_chunkCount;
    chunk->freeBlocks = (b3Block*)((unsigned char*)chunk + sizeof(b3Chunk)); //here
}
```

At the last line, the chunk pointer is first casted into unsigned char*,
why is that?

Why cant we just do that instead ?

```
chunk->freeBlocks = (b3Block*)(chunk + sizeof(b3Chunk));
```

here is the .h file for more info :

```
// Number of blocks per chunk.
const u32 b3_blockCount = 32;

// A pool of memory blocks.
class b3BlockPool
{
public:
    b3BlockPool(u32 blockSize);
    ~b3BlockPool();

    void* Allocate();
    void Free(void* p);
private:
    struct b3Block
    {
        b3Block* next;
    };

    struct b3Chunk
    {
        b3Block* freeBlocks;
        b3Chunk* next;
    };

    u32 m_blockSize;
    u32 m_chunkSize;

    b3Chunk* m_chunks;
    u32 m_chunkCount;
};
```

Comment: Should be `chunk->freeBlocks = chunk + 1` without any cast.

Comment: Your `chunk + sizeof(b3Chunk)` is not valid, because this adds `sizeof(b3Chunk) * sizeof(b3Chunk)` byte offset.

Comment: Additionally the intermediate cast to `unsigned char *` is potentially being used to mask a *Strict Aliasing* violation. If `chunk->freeBlocks` is not type `b3Block*` to begin with and that isn't a class type it is derived from, then the cast to `b3Block*` likely is a strict aliasing violation. [C++17 Standard - 7.2.1 Value Category (p11)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)

Comment: You could just replace that last part with `&chunk[1]` to get the address of the second element (Which is what it looks like your trying to do).

Comment: @S.M. the member "freeBlocks" is a b3Block pointer, so i am not sure about your solution